# Doxygen demands that an include-guard be documented

Tags: c++, doxygen, include-guards

Please do not mind the strangeness of the following minimal example (I would have to make it much larger to justify why I am doing things this way):

File test.cpp:

```
#include "a.h"

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

File a.h:

```
namespace N { // without namespace all is well!
#include "b.h"
}
```

File b.h:

```
/// \file

#ifndef GUARD
#define GUARD

struct A {};
#define CMD 5 // without this, all is well!

#endif
```

Doxygen 1.8.11 complains:

```
warning: Member GUARD (macro definition) of file a.h is not documented.
```

The first interesting thing is that the warning mentions `a.h`. The second one is that if either of the commented lines is removed, the warning disappears. What is going on here?

Comment: `a.h` doesn't have include guards ?

Comment: @old_mountain Only for minimality of the example.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [conditional documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdcond) to [suppress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506415/suppressing-doxygen-warnings) Doxygen warnings like this:

```
//b.h
/// \file

//! @cond SuppressGuard
#ifndef GUARD
#define GUARD
//! @endcond

struct A {};
//! @cond SuppressCmd
#define CMD 5 // without this, all is well!
//! @endcond

//! @cond SuppressGuard
#endif
//! @endcond
```

Note that I wrapped `#endif` with `cond`s, because otherwise you'll get if-endif mismatch warning:

```
/home/user/doxygen/b.h:13: warning: More #endif's than #if's found.
```

Comment: This is a workaround. But what was going on? Why did the warning disappear when I did not define `CMD`?