# How can I make Doxygen not document my include guard?

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen, include-guards

I'm using Doxygen 1.8.13 on a C++ project.

Generally, I want Doxygen to document my macros. However, I obviously don't want it documenting my header file [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard):

```
#ifndef FOO_H_
#define FOO_H_
... etc ...
#endif // FOO_H
```

... but Doxygen, by default, does add a documentation entry for it. I [know](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40358301/1593077) I can work around this with:

```
///@cond
#ifndef FOO_H_
#define FOO_H_
///@endcond
... etc ...
#endif // FOO_H
```

But I don't want to have to add two useless lines to every single header file! Is there anything I can do?

`doxygen.cfg` contents:

```
DOXYFILE_ENCODING      = UTF-8
PROJECT_LOGO           = 
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = docs
CREATE_SUBDIRS         = NO
ALLOW_UNICODE_NAMES    = NO
OUTPUT_LANGUAGE        = English
BRIEF_MEMBER_DESC      = YES
REPEAT_BRIEF           = YES
ALWAYS_DETAILED_SEC    = NO
INLINE_INHERITED_MEMB  = NO
FULL_PATH_NAMES        = YES
STRIP_FROM_PATH        = 
SHORT_NAMES            = NO
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      = YES
QT_AUTOBRIEF           = NO
MULTILINE_CPP_IS_BRIEF = NO
INHERIT_DOCS           = YES
SEPARATE_MEMBER_PAGES  = NO
TAB_SIZE               = 4
ALIASES                = selfdocumenting="&nbsp;"
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = NO
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_JAVA   = NO
OPTIMIZE_FOR_FORTRAN   = NO
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_VHDL   = NO
EXTENSION_MAPPING      = cu=C++ cuh=C++ cuhpp=C++ hpp=C++
MARKDOWN_SUPPORT       = YES
AUTOLINK_SUPPORT       = YES
BUILTIN_STL_SUPPORT    = YES
CPP_CLI_SUPPORT        = NO
SIP_SUPPORT            = NO
IDL_PROPERTY_SUPPORT   = YES
DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC   = NO
GROUP_NESTED_COMPOUNDS = NO
SUBGROUPING            = YES
INLINE_GROUPED_CLASSES = NO
INLINE_SIMPLE_STRUCTS  = NO
TYPEDEF_HIDES_STRUCT   = NO
LOOKUP_CACHE_SIZE      = 2
EXTRACT_ALL            = NO
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = NO
EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = NO
EXTRACT_STATIC         = NO
EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES  = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = NO
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES   = NO
HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS     = NO
HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES     = NO
HIDE_FRIEND_COMPOUNDS  = NO
HIDE_IN_BODY_DOCS      = YES
INTERNAL_DOCS          = NO
CASE_SENSE_NAMES       = YES
HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES       = NO
HIDE_COMPOUND_REFERENCE= NO
SHOW_INCLUDE_FILES     = YES
SHOW_GROUPED_MEMB_INC  = NO
FORCE_LOCAL_INCLUDES   = NO
INLINE_INFO            = YES
SORT_MEMBER_DOCS       = YES
SORT_BRIEF_DOCS        = NO
SORT_MEMBERS_CTORS_1ST = NO
SORT_GROUP_NAMES       = NO
SORT_BY_SCOPE_NAME     = NO
STRICT_PROTO_MATCHING  = NO
GENERATE_TODOLIST      = YES
GENERATE_TESTLIST      = YES
GENERATE_BUGLIST       = YES
GENERATE_DEPRECATEDLIST= YES
MAX_INITIALIZER_LINES  = 30
SHOW_USED_FILES        = YES
SHOW_FILES             = YES
SHOW_NAMESPACES        = YES
QUIET                  = NO
WARNINGS               = YES
WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED   = YES
WARN_IF_DOC_ERROR      = YES
WARN_NO_PARAMDOC       = NO
WARN_AS_ERROR          = NO
WARN_FORMAT            = "$file:$line: $text"
INPUT                  = src/ README.md
INPUT_ENCODING         = UTF-8
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.c *.cc *.cxx *.cpp *.c++ *.java *.ii *.ixx *.ipp *.i++ *.inl *.idl *.ddl *.odl *.h *.hh *.hxx *.hpp *.h++ *.cs *.d *.php *.php4 *.php5 *.phtml *.inc *.m *.markdown *.md *.mm *.dox *.py *.pyw *.f90 *.f *.for *.tcl *.vhd *.vhdl *.ucf *.qsf *.as *.js *.cuh *.cu *.cuhpp
RECURSIVE              = YES
EXCLUDE                = 
EXCLUDE_SYMLINKS       = NO
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS       = */detail/*
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        = *_H_, *_CUH_, *_HPP_, *::detail*, detail:*, *_impl, std::*
EXAMPLE_RECURSIVE      = NO
FILTER_SOURCE_FILES    = NO
USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE = README.md
SOURCE_BROWSER         = NO
INLINE_SOURCES         = NO
STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS    = YES
REFERENCED_BY_RELATION = NO
REFERENCES_RELATION    = NO
REFERENCES_LINK_SOURCE = YES
SOURCE_TOOLTIPS        = YES
USE_HTAGS              = NO
VERBATIM_HEADERS       = YES
CLANG_ASSISTED_PARSING = NO
ALPHABETICAL_INDEX     = YES
COLS_IN_ALPHA_INDEX    = 5
GENERATE_HTML          = YES
HTML_OUTPUT            = html
HTML_FILE_EXTENSION    = .html
HTML_COLORSTYLE_HUE    = 220
HTML_COLORSTYLE_SAT    = 100
HTML_COLORSTYLE_GAMMA  = 80
HTML_TIMESTAMP         = NO
HTML_DYNAMIC_SECTIONS  = NO
HTML_INDEX_NUM_ENTRIES = 100
GENERATE_DOCSET        = NO
DOCSET_FEEDNAME        = "Doxygen generated docs"
DOCSET_BUNDLE_ID       = org.doxygen.Project
DOCSET_PUBLISHER_ID    = org.doxygen.Publisher
DOCSET_PUBLISHER_NAME  = Publisher
GENERATE_HTMLHELP      = NO
GENERATE_CHI           = NO
BINARY_TOC             = NO
TOC_EXPAND             = NO
GENERATE_QHP           = NO
QHP_NAMESPACE          = org.doxygen.Project
QHP_VIRTUAL_FOLDER     = doc
GENERATE_ECLIPSEHELP   = NO
ECLIPSE_DOC_ID         = org.doxygen.Project
DISABLE_INDEX          = NO
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = NO
ENUM_VALUES_PER_LINE   = 1
TREEVIEW_WIDTH         = 250
EXT_LINKS_IN_WINDOW    = NO
FORMULA_FONTSIZE       = 10
FORMULA_TRANSPARENT    = YES
USE_MATHJAX            = NO
MATHJAX_FORMAT         = HTML-CSS
MATHJAX_RELPATH        = http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest
SEARCHENGINE           = YES
SERVER_BASED_SEARCH    = NO
EXTERNAL_SEARCH        = NO
SEARCHDATA_FILE        = searchdata.xml
GENERATE_LATEX         = YES
LATEX_OUTPUT           = latex
LATEX_CMD_NAME         = latex
MAKEINDEX_CMD_NAME     = makeindex
COMPACT_LATEX          = NO
PAPER_TYPE             = a4
PDF_HYPERLINKS         = YES
USE_PDFLATEX           = YES
LATEX_BATCHMODE        = NO
LATEX_HIDE_INDICES     = NO
LATEX_SOURCE_CODE      = NO
LATEX_BIB_STYLE        = plain
LATEX_TIMESTAMP        = NO
GENERATE_RTF           = NO
RTF_OUTPUT             = rtf
COMPACT_RTF            = NO
RTF_HYPERLINKS         = NO
RTF_SOURCE_CODE        = NO
GENERATE_MAN           = NO
MAN_OUTPUT             = man
MAN_EXTENSION          = .3
MAN_LINKS              = NO
GENERATE_XML           = NO
XML_OUTPUT             = xml
XML_PROGRAMLISTING     = YES
GENERATE_DOCBOOK       = NO
DOCBOOK_OUTPUT         = docbook
DOCBOOK_PROGRAMLISTING = NO
GENERATE_AUTOGEN_DEF   = NO
GENERATE_PERLMOD       = NO
PERLMOD_LATEX          = NO
PERLMOD_PRETTY         = YES
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = YES
SEARCH_INCLUDES        = YES
PREDEFINED             = protected=private # will prevent extraction of protected members
PREDEFINED             += " __CUDA_ARCH__=610"
PREDEFINED             += " __CUDACC__=1"
PREDEFINED             += " __NVCC__=1"
SKIP_FUNCTION_MACROS   = YES
TAGFILES               += "docs/cppreference-doxygen-web.tag.xml=http://en.cppreference.com/w/"
ALLEXTERNALS           = NO
EXTERNAL_GROUPS        = YES
EXTERNAL_PAGES         = YES
PERL_PATH              = /usr/bin/perl
CLASS_DIAGRAMS         = YES
HIDE_UNDOC_RELATIONS   = YES
HAVE_DOT               = YES
DOT_NUM_THREADS        = 0
DOT_FONTNAME           = Helvetica
DOT_FONTSIZE           = 10
CLASS_GRAPH            = YES
COLLABORATION_GRAPH    = YES
GROUP_GRAPHS           = YES
UML_LOOK               = NO
UML_LIMIT_NUM_FIELDS   = 10
TEMPLATE_RELATIONS     = NO
INCLUDE_GRAPH          = NO
INCLUDED_BY_GRAPH      = NO
CALL_GRAPH             = NO
CALLER_GRAPH           = NO
GRAPHICAL_HIERARCHY    = YES
DIRECTORY_GRAPH        = YES
DOT_IMAGE_FORMAT       = png
INTERACTIVE_SVG        = NO
DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES    = 50
MAX_DOT_GRAPH_DEPTH    = 0
DOT_TRANSPARENT        = NO
DOT_MULTI_TARGETS      = NO
GENERATE_LEGEND        = YES
DOT_CLEANUP            = YES
```

Comment: Related: [Doxygen demands that an include-guard be documented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358150/doxygen-demands-that-an-include-guard-be-documented)

Comment: Please specify the doxygen version. Please include the Doxyfile (at least the changes compared to the default Doxyfile, with 1.8.15 and newer use doxn -x to obtain this information).

Comment: @albert: Sorry, see edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the documentation:

> EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS The EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS tag can be used to specify one or
>   more symbol names (namespaces, classes, functions, etc.) that should
>   be excluded from the output. The symbol name can be a fully qualified
>   name, a word, or if the wildcard * is used, a substring. Examples:
>   ANamespace, AClass, A -Class::ANamespace, ANamespace::*Test

So in your case e.g. setting in the Doxyfile:

```
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS         = *_H_
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        += *_HPP_
```

or

```
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS         = *_H_ \
                          *_HPP_
```

Comment: Is that list is separated by `, `, or by `,` and any amount of namespace?

Comment: In 1.8.15 it should be possible to use a `,` but in 1.8.13 a space is required or use the `+=` possibility. I think any amount of namespace is possible, but in the a namespace for the quard??